# Hibernate - Path expected for join

Tags: hibernate

I have a hibernate query like this

```
SELECT t FROM User t JOIN UserRole u ON t.username = u.username WHERE t.username=:username AND t.password =:pass AND u.userRole =:ust
```

But this query doesn't work
**Error**

> ERROR:    Path expected for join!
>   ERROR:    Path expected for join!
>    Path expected for join!
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:385)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3903)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3689)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3567)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:708)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:564)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:249)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:278)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
>       at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
>       at com.nepitc.mshandloomfrabics.daoimp.UserDAOImp.login(UserDAOImp.java:40)
>       at com.nepitc.mshandloomfrabics.service.UserService.login(UserService.java:74)
>       at com.nepitc.mshandloomfrabics.controller.AuthorizationController.login(AuthorizationController.java:38)

How can I write it correctly

Comment: Your join syntax is off, for one thing, probably leading to the immediate error you face.  For this and other errors, please read the official documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen While much of this hasn't changed in a while, it's probably more appropriate to link to more updated documentation than the older 3.3 release from 10 years ago.

Comment: Please include both the full error and entity mappings for both entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPQL / HQL you do not need to specify the `ON` clause for the join because Hibernate already knows the mappings between the two entities and the columns required to generate said join.

So you really only need to supply the predicatesand the request to perform the join as follows

```
SELECT u FROM User u 
  JOIN u.roles ur
 WHERE u.username = :username
   AND u.password = :password
   AND ur.userRole = :role
```

Comment: How does Hibernate know to use the `username` column to join, as opposed to some other column?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I simply made the assumption that both entities are likely related via some association, therefore its unnecessary to specify the join conditions in that context regardless of what columns the two entities are associated by.  But it seems the entity mappings will tell the story of how best to write the query when they're provided.

Comment: Ok let me add mapping between these two entities.